# HTTP 200 - parsererror MACOSX during the installation of prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to install PrestaShop 1.7.5.0 on my MAC  and I am seeing a HTTP PARSE ERROR 200.

Has anyone had this problem or know how to solve it ?

(i pin the photo of the error [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2k7x.png))

Comment: This error may have different causes according to PS forum https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/664396-http-200-parsererror-during-installation-process/ and forge issue tracker:http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/BOOM-1892. Can you check different possibilies like changing browser....

Comment: thanks, it was just a browser issue.

Comment: You are welcome